# moving span to the left with pull-left doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">

       <div class="span5"> 
       </div>

       <div class="span3">
       </div>

       <div class="span4"> 
       </div>  

 </div>
```

I want to move "span3" completely to the left, so I changed my code to:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">

       <div class="span5"> 
       </div>

       <div class="span3 pull-left">
       </div>

       <div class="span4"> 
       </div>  

 </div>
```

But this doesn't work. If I add pull-right to the span5 the span5 moves to the right. Why moving span3 to the left doesn't work ?

I can ofcourse change the order of the span's in the html, but for seo reasons I do not want span3 in the beginning of the page...

Comment: Ehhh, it is only the Twitter bootstrap css... pull-left is defined as .pull-left {float: left;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by default in a row-fluid all spans will float left, so adding pull-left (which is basically float:left) will have no effect.  And as far as I know pull-left and pull-right were not intended to be used in the grid system.

I know that doesn't answer your question, but that's what I'm seeing just glancing at the chrome inspector

EDIT:
It looks like you can't currently do this without some heavy hacking.  You can check out this Issue that talks about just what you're trying to do.  Some members have posted solutions it looks like.

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4488

Comment: Same issue with BT 3, kinda dumb that you can't float a span to the right with pull-right..